# How to Add Expires headers to Google ,Twitter and Facebook js files?

Tags: .htaccess

I performed an yslow test and wondered there is an f grade for expire headers, but i set an expire headers, later i came to know that the js files are out of my server ,how to add the expire headers to external js files from twitter and facebook, my apache version was 2,

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js
https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from:rgvzoomin+OR+from:Samanthaprabhu2+OR+from:NameisNani+OR+from:purijagan+OR+from:harish2you+OR+from:charmmeofficial+OR+from:nandinireddy4u+OR+from:sneha_ullal+OR+from:trishtrashers+OR+from:LakshmiManchu+OR+from:shrutihaasan+OR+from:RanaDaggubati+OR+from:geneliad+OR+from:urstruelybunny+OR+from:urstrulyMahesh+OR+from:Ileana_Dcruz+OR+from:allarinaresh+OR+from:ramsayz+OR+from:prakashraaj+OR+from:Actor_Siddharth+OR+from:richyricha+OR+from:iamnagarjuna+OR+from:ssrajamouli&callback=TweetTick&rpp=5
http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js
http://gobnf.org/i/wm/buttons/wm_super.gif
http://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tolly2day.com&callback=twttr.receiveCount
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't control the headers being sent with these files since they are not being sent from your server.  You can only control the headers of files you are hosting locally.